# Debezium Server MongoDB connector Enabling the Signalling doesn't work

Tags: debezium, debezium-server

I run the Debezium Server with source MongoDB and sink Kinesis on k8s. After enabling the signalling by setting

```
DEBEZIUM_SOURCE_SIGNAL_DATA_COLLECTION="test.debezium_signaling"
DEBEZIUM_SOURCE_COLLECTION_INCLUDE_LIST: "<some other existing collections>,test.debezium_signaling"
```

and restarting the pod and inserting

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "***"
  },
  "type": "execute-snapshot",
  "data": "{'data-collections': ['test.new_collection']}"
}
```

nothing happens and debezium seems to be stuck at the `checking current members of replica set at ...`

There aren't any errors, any idea what could be the issue?

I also enabled the debug logs but there aren't any logs indicating that the signaling record is picked up by the server